# Cross reference-class and return map<string, Class>

Tags: c++, dictionary

There are two problems which I can't seem to figure out , input is appreciated.

In my program there are two classes `Parser` and `Rules`. In the class `Parser`, I should return a map with rules using `extract_rules()` function, but I encounter two problems:

1. How do I reference `Rules` in the `parser.h` file? Rules are needed because the `extract_rules()` function should return a `map<int, Rules>` Only doing `#include rules.h` triggers another string of errors ...
2. There is a compile error when the return type is set to `map<int, Rules>` for `extract_rules()` , how may I resolve this problem? If the return type is `void`, no problem is encountered whatsoever and the program runs fine.

**rules.h**

```
Class Rules
{
public:

string rule_name;
string function_name;
}
```

**parser.h**

```
Class Parser
{
public:

map<int, Rules> extract_rules();
}
```

**parser.cpp**

```
using namespace std;

map<int, Rules> extract_rules()
{
map<int, Rules> rules_map;
int count;
Rules r;
r.rule_name = "Rule 1";
r.function_name = "Function 1";
rules_map.emplace(count, r);
return rules_map;
}
```

Reminder not to code when you're tired: forgot to `#include <map>` in Rules.h. Thanks everyone. Upvoted.

Comment: How about telling us the errors? And the include for (1) is correct.

Comment: We need to know what errors are being produced first!

Comment: You may want to give `count` a value before using it, otherwise it contains a random value.

Comment: I will post the errors when I get home, thanks for the remarks so far. Are there other things to correct in my code or all looks in order?

Comment: ...and you shouldn't remove things which could be relevant, like the includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the macros to restrict multiple inclusion (of your header files) in each of your header file like below:-

```
#ifndef RULES_H
#define RULES_H

#include <map> //header file for map
#include <string> //header file for string
using namespace std;


#endif //RULES_H
```

and You have to define the function in parser.cpp like below:-

```
map<int, Rules> Parser::extract_rules(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing

```
#pragma once
```

at the beggining of rules.h and then including it in parser.h
I also can't see

```
#include <map>
```

which should also be in parser.h.